# Javascript with python cgi not giving expected results

Tags: python, cgi

In the below Python CGI script, I am using javascript function for changing the picture on click. But apparently it doesn't seems to work. I am following the example from [w3 schools js example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lightbulb). So I just want to conform, is it possible to use the javascript inside Python CGI script.

If same example has to be done in Python, what should be the approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi

print """print "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function changeImage()
{
element=document.getElementById('myimage')
if (element.src.match("bulbon"))
  {
  element.src="../pic_bulboff.gif";
  }
else
  {
  element.src="../pic_bulbon.gif";
  }
}
</script>

<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()"
src="../pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light</p>

</body>
</html>

"""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can send javascript inside the HTML via a python CGI scrpit. You have to change the initial part of the string that you are sending to:

```
print """Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

**EDIT** to add the following comments:

There were two problems in your code:

the 1st, you had to remove the part 'print "', because you were already printing a string;

the 2nd, it is a specification of CGI that it must have "\n\n" separating the header, eg. "content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n" from the following part eg. "...", (in fact as you had one implicit "\n", it would be enough to add just one more...).

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot !! Can you please tell me what happened with changing the initial part of the string, (its significance) ?

Comment: @sarbjit There were two problems - the 1st trivial, and the 2nd difficult to discover by yourself: see the info that I've added to my answer for the details.